# Валидация формы html перед отправкой через JS?

Tags: post, ajax, php, html, javascript

А вообще все отмена по другому решил!
есть у меня такая форма

```
<form action="page.cgi" onreset="return confirm("Вы действительно хотите сбросить    форму?");" onsubmit="return confirm();">
<input type = "submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

она при нажатии кнопки субмит выдает окно с кнопками ДА и НЕТ - понятно для чего они)
```

1) мне надо сделатьчто бы вместо окна confirm вылезало окно prompt и при введени в него нужной фразы форма улетала, и

2) Поечему то окно не смотря на то что ему указан параметр "Вы действительно хотите сбросить    форму?" подписанно как "undefinent"?

Comment: сделайте var_dump для массива $_POST. Возможно там данные хранятся не так как вы ожидаете...

Comment: нет он просто не переходит туда..

Comment: А в "обработчик" ваш оно хоть вообще заходит?
Совет: используйте [дебагер][1]


[1]http://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался сам! Сделал ссылку на функцию JS

```
<a href="#" onclick="Delete(); return false;">Удалить</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Delete() {
var del=prompt('Вы действительно собираетесь безвозвратно удалить  коалицию со всеми файлами, записями и сообщениям? Для подтвержения действия введите "Удалить"')
if(del=="Удалить")      document.getElementById("DeleteEnter").submit();

};
</script>
```

которая запускала уже форму!

```
<form name="DeleteEnter" id="DeleteEnter"  action="coalition_delet.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: 'foo='+foo,
```

**data** должен быть объектом, а не текстом

```
data: {'foo':foo}
```

Comment: и так не работает(

Comment: @zhenyab, не обязательно. там у него правильно написано. @DanteLoL, а где вы вызываете функцию count_delete ??

Comment: оу пардон забыл вставить там у меня под скриптом ссылка такая 

    <a onclick="count_delete()" href="">Click me</a>